# filtering output of who with grep and cut

Tags: linux, bash

I have this exercice :

> Create a bash script that check if the user passed as a parameter is
>   connected and if he is display when he connected. Indications : use the command who, the grep filter and the
>   command cut.

But i have some trouble to solve it.

```
#!/bin/bash
who>who.txt;
then
    grep $1 who.txt
    for a in who.txt
    do
        echo "$a"
    done
else
    echo "$1 isnt connected"
fi
```

So first of all i want to only keep the line where i can find the user in a .txt and then i want to cut each part with a loop in the who command to keep only the date but the problem is that i don't know how to cut here because it's seperated with multiple spaces.

So i'am really blocked and i don't see where to go to do this. I'am a beginner with bash.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `if` at the start of your script? It would be useful to show a sample of the output of `who`.

Comment: You might want to look into the “pipe” feature for sending the output of one command directly into another command. For example, you could pipe the output of `who` into `grep`, and the output of `grep` into `cut`, all in one pipeline.

Comment: Note that `for a in who.txt` doesn't loop over the *contents* of `who.txt`.  The loop runs once, with `a=who.txt`.  See the Bash FAQ (linked in my answer) for how to parse files.  You *could* solve this whole problem with `who | while IFS= read ...`, in pure bash (except for `who`), instead of using `grep` and `cut` at all, if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cut` is a rather awkward tool for parsing `who`'s output, unless you use fixed column positions.  In delimiter mode, with `-d ' '`, each space makes a separate empty field.  It's not like `awk` where fields are separated by a run of spaces.

`who(1)` output looks like this (and GNU `who` has no option to cut it down to *just* the username/time):

```
$ who
peter    tty1         2015-11-13 18:53
john     pts/13       2015-11-12 08:44 (10.0.0.1)
john     pts/14       2015-11-12 08:44 (10.0.0.1)
john     pts/15       2015-11-12 08:44 (10.0.0.1)
john     pts/16       2015-11-12 08:44 (10.0.0.1)
peter    pts/9        2015-11-14 16:09 (:0)
```

I didn't check what happens with very long usernames, whether they're truncated or whether they shift the rest of the line over.  Parsing it with `awk '{print $3, $4}` would feel much safer, since it would still work regardless of exact column position.

But since you need to use `cut`, let's assume that those exact column positions (time starting from 23 and running until 38) are constant across all systems where we want this script to work, and all terminal widths.  (`who` doesn't appear to vary its output for `$COLUMNS` or the tty-driver column width (the `columns` field in `stty -a` output)).

Putting all that together:

```
#!/bin/sh
who | grep "^$1 " | cut -c 23-38
```

The regex on the grep command line will only match at the beginning of the line, and has to match a space following the username (to avoid substring matches).  Then those lines that match are filtered through `cut`, to extract only the columns containing the timestamp.

With an empty cmdline arg, will print the login time for *every* logged-in user.  If the pattern doesn't match anything, the output will be empty.  To explicitly detect this and print something else, capture the pipeline output with `var=$(pipeline)`, and test if it's the empty-string or not.

This will print a time for every separate login from the same user.  You could use grep's count limit arg (see the man page) to stop after one match, but it might not be the most recent time.  You might use `sort -n | head -1` or something.

---

If you don't have to write a loop in the shell, don't.  It's much better to write a pipeline that makes one pass over the data.  The shell itself is slow, but as long as it doesn't have to parse every line of what you're dealing with, that doesn't matter.

Also note how I quoted the expansion of `$1` with double quotes, to avoid the shell applying word splitting and glob expansion to it.

For more shell stuff, see [the Wooledge Bash FAQ and guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).  That's a good place to get started learning idioms that don't suck (i.e. don't break when you have filenames and directories with spaces in them, or filenames containing a `?`, or lines with trailing spaces that you want to not munge...).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you simply want to check to see if a user is logged in, then that is what the `users` command is for. If you want to wrap it in a short script, then you could do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && {  ## validate 1 argument given on command line
    printf "error: insufficient input, usage: %s username.\n" "${0##*/}" >&2
    exit 1
}

## check if that argument is among the logged in users
if $(users | grep -q "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1) ; then
    printf " user: %s is logged in.\n" "$1"
else
    printf " user: %s is NOT logged in.\n" "$1"
fi
```

**Example/Use**

```
$ bash chkuser.sh dog
 user: dog is NOT logged in.

$ bash chkuser.sh david
 user: david is logged in.
```

Comment: What's the advantage to putting the `grep` pipeline inside a command substitution, instead of just `if who | grep -q ...;then`?  You don't want the pipeline to print any output that's not redirected to /dev/null either way, because it'll be run as a command instead of showing up as script output.

Comment: Probably more useful is to capture the output into a variable, so he can filter it with `cut` to get the login time.

Comment: Agreed. Putting the results of `users` into an array, etc.. is always an option, but not knowing the level of expertise of the questioner, I was reluctant to overly complicate the solution with the additional syntax, etc.. -- Additionally, the question is now quite a bit different than it was when I answered.

Comment: Oh, did the OP make some edits in the first 5 mins after posting?  The revision list is just original->my retitle.  It took me a while to spot the actual desired output, but it's there in the homework-assignment he quoted.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the original question was basically just the first sentence when I answered it.